# Vertically Center Multi-Lined Text | Latex

Tags: pdftex, tikz-pgf, xetex

```
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\Large\uppercase{Note - 1}}\\ 
        \vspace{24pt}
        \textbf{\Large\uppercase{Data analysis}}
    \end{center}
```

with this piece of code I am able to get a horizontal centre alignment . But I also want the text to be vertically aligned too.

The vertical alignment I want in such a way that the vertical centre should be in the middle of these 2 lines. How to do that in latex.?

**result of @Patrick Ferguson:**

[image: Its not properly centre aligned vertically]
<-- result

The code I am using is,

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.3cm,bottom=2.3cm, footskip=42pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [remember picture, overlay] \draw[line width=3pt] ($(current page.north west)+(2.5cm,-1.5cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1.5cm,1.5cm)$);
        [remember picture, overlay] \draw[line width=1pt] ($(current page.north west)+(2.6cm,-1.6cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1.6cm,1.6cm)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \phantom{*} % \phantom => invisible
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\Large\uppercase{Note - 1}}\\ 
        \vspace{24pt}
        \textbf{\Large\uppercase{Data analysis}}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \phantom{*}

    \newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of manually numbering chapters and inserting markup, you should rather look into customising the display of chapters. For example the `titlesec` or `FncyChap` packages might be interesting. Also the syntax `\Large{...}` is wrong. `\Large` is a switch and does not take an argument.

Comment: ... and don't abuse `\\ ` for line breaks outside of tables.

Comment: The result you get from @Patrick Ferguson will center the content with respect to the text area (more or less as your usage of fontsize changes is wrong and won't properly adjust the baselineskip) You could also have it centred with respect to the whole page, e.g. with tikz pagenodes, but without a [mre] its hard to give you code that would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using tikz to draw the boarder, simply use a node to place the text in the centre of the page (just for visualisation I added the red dot to the centre of the page):

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex % | xelatex %

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.3cm,bottom=2.3cm, footskip=42pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[line width=3pt] ($(current page.north west)+(2.5cm,-1.5cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1.5cm,1.5cm)$);
        \draw[line width=1pt] ($(current page.north west)+(2.6cm,-1.6cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east)+(-1.6cm,1.6cm)$);
        \fill[red] (current page.center) circle (0.1);
        \node[font=\Large\bfseries, text width=5cm,align=center] at (current page.center) {
            \uppercase{Note -- 1}

            \vspace{24pt}

            \uppercase{Data analysis}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newpage

    test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe you want it centred to your frame and not the whole page?

```
% !TeX document-id = {a3867b77-1acb-4c22-aa49-faff0df3de47}
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex % | xelatex %

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=3.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.3cm,bottom=2.3cm, footskip=42pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \coordinate  (A) at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5cm,-1.5cm)$) ;
      \coordinate  (B) at ($(current page.south east)+(-1.5cm,1.5cm)$) ;
        \draw[line width=3pt] (A) rectangle (B);
        \draw[line width=1pt] ($(A)+(0.1cm,-0.1cm)$) rectangle ($(B)+(-0.1cm,0.1cm)$);
        \node[font=\Large\bfseries, text width=5cm,align=center] at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {
            \uppercase{Note -- 1}

            \vspace{24pt}

            \uppercase{Data analysis}
        };        
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newpage

    test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just one more doubt , the boarder I have made is currently applied only to the "current" page. How can I apply boarder to all pages. (Globally)

Comment: @AjitJoseph if you have a new question, please use the `ask question" button at the top right

Answer (score 2):

An ad hoc solution is:

```
{latex}
\phantom{*} % \phantom => invisible
\vfill
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Large\uppercase{Note - 1}}\\ 
    \vspace{24pt}
    \textbf{\Large\uppercase{Data analysis}}
\end{center}
\vfill
\phantom{*}
```

giving:

[image: pdf output]

If you intend to create several titles, it would be better to define a title style using `titlesec`, per @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 's comment.

Comment: I am sorry , but Its look like I am not getting the result I wanted